# Enviar Datos por ajax libreria TCPDF

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdf

Necesito enviar datos desde ajax a un pdf , pero al momento de imprimir el dato se pierde, existe alguna configuración de TCPDF, para que responda a las peticiones ajax?

```
function ComprobanteCliente()
{

    $.post("<?= base_url() ?>PdfImprimirController/GeneraImpresionPDF/CHECKLIST CLIENTE", {
                'id_cliente':$('#hddndi').val()          
            });
}
```

TCPDF

Al momento de escribir la url

```
PdfImprimirController/GeneraImpresionPDF/ENTREGA%20DE%20VEHICULO
```

el pdf se ejecuta , con la opción "I" lo imprimo sin guardar, lo que no consigo hacer es que reciba la variable ajax

```
$data['id_cliente']=$this->input->post('id_cliente');
```

y imprima al mismo tiempo gracias

```
$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
```

Al momento de enviar la petición ajax al pdf el network de google chrome genera una una codificación que no interpreta el navegador

Esto es un fragmento de lo muestra

```
%PDF-1.7
%âãÏÓ
16 0 obj
<< /Type /Page /Parent 1 0 R /LastModified (D:20170329202948+02'00') /Resources 2 0 R /MediaBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /CropBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /BleedBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /TrimBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /ArtBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /Contents 17 0 R /Rotate 0 /Group << /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB >> /PZ 1 >>
endobj
17 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 1846>> stream
xí\ÛVÛ8Õs¾Bíî¶x£Ðë*m¡´/mWW&KB)ÓùªùµùÙm¢Ø!M88Y¶Étnû]bÎLÂñ¡ÓW8¾ÑO_pÙÅñÇ~ëÉm?ThÆÃîìÑ§;->«mTÉÆ:$"±D¿¥
SFÛÔPÔÎnM¨ák­âtE¬.Aû=ºGÑçÝQ7}oìÌ½¹aå-­Ë¨1ÚZ¡%=¦\¤VN;G¨HKUZ]?¨å¾¿)í­ÖXAý¡ôZ­á¡ê¨%>Cïfyfº®·ÎZÒâT²Wb§
"ïÏVíuÐ<_)_«JeÒJg-¡ínÐ­EaÌüJ[[Yvj2ª][×=wO¢I4Óä]¢E   ',1ÜCæÎ.ýô<%oÈÙÆõ9Y#l
```

Comment: Tu pretendes que el AJAX te responda con un PDF???

Comment: Estoy usando una función ajax que no espera respuesta. $.post , aun así no puedo generar el pdf, con este dato "$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');" de la libreria TCPDF ,puedo generar el pdf , pero sin el dato que estoy enviando por ajax

Comment: es que al parecer el pdf ya se ha generado con la respuesta que pusiste (con la del fragmento comentado) solo debes agregar ese fragmento a un tag object

Comment: exacto el pdf se genera pero no puedo acceder  su url desde ajax, por que cuando envio la petición el pdf aun no existe  , ese es mi problema

Comment: sigo sin entender de qué va el problema, lo que quieres es modificar el PDF que se genera?

Comment: lo que quiero es tomar los datos que tengo por pantalla para evitar hacer una query y mandarlos por ajax al pdf pero sin guardar el pdf, solo mostralo

Answer (score 0):

```
<object id="pdf" data="" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>

<script>
// como te puedes dar cuenta, para pasar los datos usamos un arreglo
// para recuperar la respuesta agregamos un metodo llamado .done, y es ahi donde recuperamos el PDF.
$.post( "tu.php", {id_cliente:"123")
.done(function( data ) {
   //Aquí se debería regresar el contenido del PDF.
   ahora solo lo agregamos en el object.
   $( "#pdf" ).html( data );
});
</script>
```

Comment: De que forma le pasaria el dato que quiero mandar por ajax?

Comment: @JavierAntonioAguayoAguilar Ya he actualizado la respuesta, verificala, saludos

Comment: No estaría de más decir cómo este código resuelve la pregunta. Algún comentario, algo

Answer (score 0):

Yo también he intentado de todo y no puedo desde un ajax jquery post, pero lo he conseguido de la siguiente manera:

**Código HTML:**

```
<button type="button" onclick="imprimir();">Imprimir</button>
```

**Código PHP:** (archivo: actions.php) Genera el PDF con TCPDF

```
// Recibe parámetros mediante POST
if (isset($_POST['campo1'])) { $campo1 = $_POST['campo1']; }
if (isset($_POST['campo2'])) { $campo1 = $_POST['campo2']; }
// ... //Otras lineas de código que generan tu PDF.
// Muestra tu PDF sin guardar en disco, en el popup creado desde el javascript.
$pdf->Output('archivo.pdf', 'I');
```

**Código JS:**

```
function imprimir () {
  // pon AQUI tu codigo AJAX para otras acciones previas
  var mapForm = document.createElement("form");
  mapForm.target = "newFormWindow";
  mapForm.method = "POST";
  mapForm.action = "actions.php"; // PHP con código para mostrar el PDF
  // Crea los inputs
  var mapInput1 = document.createElement("input");
  var mapInput2 = document.createElement("input");
  mapInput1.type = "text";
  mapInput1.name = "campo1";
  mapInput1.value = "valor1";
  mapInput2.type = "text";
  mapInput2.name = "campo2";
  mapInput2.value = "valor2";
  mapForm.appendChild(mapInput1);
  mapForm.appendChild(mapInput2);
  document.body.appendChild(mapForm);
  // Adiciona form a dom
  document.body.appendChild(mapForm);
  // Abre nueva ventana popup (fullscreen) donde se mostrará la información
  window.open("", "newFormWindow", "height="+screen.height+",width="+screen.width+",resizable=yes");
  // submit form
  mapForm.submit();
  // pon AQUI tu codigo AJAX para otras acciones posteriores
}
```